# php table: display 3 cells in each row

Tags: php, html-table

I looked here:
[Array into a table with 5 cells in each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099568/array-into-a-table-with-5-cells-in-each-row)

but I cannot adapt my code..

I need to display PHP array results in a table.
The table needs to have 3 cells for each row.

I don't know how to output the `<tr>` and `</tr>` every 3rd row, and I don't know how to output the last `</tr>` in case the table contains a number of records which is not a multiple of 3.

Here is my code:

```
echo "<table>";


$num=mysql_numrows($result1);
$i=0;
while ($i < $num)

{


$aaa=mysql_result   ($result1,$i,"aaa");
$bbb=mysql_result   ($result1,$i,"bbb");

echo "

<td>$aaa $bbb</td> ";

$i++;

}



echo "</table>";
```

Comment: How many database rows do you have per `<td>...</td>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the mod operator % to check for the third element. e.g.

```
if($i%3 == 0) {
  // this is the third element, start a new tr here
}
```

Comment: At the end, you do something like `$empty_cells=$i%3` and use a while loop to draw $empty_cells more tds. You might find it a good idea to replace the literal "3" with a variable so that this code is easy to copy and paste into other projects where you need a different number of col per row.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
echo "<table><tr>";
$num=mysql_numrows($result1);
$i=0;

while ($i < $num)
{
  $aaa=mysql_result   ($result1,$i,"aaa");
  $bbb=mysql_result   ($result1,$i,"bbb");
  if($i %3 ==0)
  {
     echo"</tr><tr><td> $aaa $bbb </td>";  
  }
  else
  {
    echo"<td> $aaa $bbb </td>";  
  }
  $i++;
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve something like this:

[image]

You can easily make things configureable by wrapping it into an `iterator` of it's own that provides rows and columns:

```
/**
 * function to fetch one row from database
 */
function fetch_row($resultSet = NULL) {
    static $result;
    static $i = 0;
    if ($resultSet) {
        $result = $resultSet;
        return;
    }
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}

fetch_row($result1); // initialize fetch function

$it = new FetchIterator('fetch_row');

$table = new TableIterator($it, 5);

if ($table->valid()) : ?>

<table border="1">

    <?php foreach ($table as $row => $columns) : ?>

        <tr class="<?php echo $row % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>">

            <?php foreach ($columns as $index => $column) : ?>

            <td>
                <?php if ($column) echo $column['aaa'], ' ', $column['bbb']; ?>
            </td>

           <?php endforeach; ?>

        </tr>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

</table>

<?php endif;
```

Some [Demo](http://codepad.org/eH0xQayz) and see as well [Some PHP Iterator Fun](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2012/02/28/some-php-iterator-fun/).