# Multiple image in a table

Tags: php, html, image

I want to know  how to show multiple image in a table like as given format

```
1stimage    2nd image   3rd image
4thimage    5th image   6th image
7thimage    8thimage    ........
```

These images are coming from a database.There may be many images in the database.

Please help me?

Comment: 1. What have you tried? 2. Are you really going to use a table for layouting purposes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php table: display 3 cells in each row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464154/php-table-display-3-cells-in-each-row)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve something like this:

[image]

You can easily make things configureable by wrapping it into an `iterator` of it's own that provides rows and columns:

```
/**
 * function to fetch one row from database
 */
function fetch_row($resultSet = NULL) {
    static $result;
    static $i = 0;
    if ($resultSet) {
        $result = $resultSet;
        return;
    }
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}

fetch_row($result1); // initialize fetch function

$it = new FetchIterator('fetch_row');

$table = new TableIterator($it, 5);

if ($table->valid()) : ?>

<table border="1">

    <?php foreach ($table as $row => $columns) : ?>

        <tr class="<?php echo $row % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>">

            <?php foreach ($columns as $index => $column) : ?>

            <td>
                <?php if ($column) echo $column['aaa'], ' ', $column['bbb']; ?>
            </td>

           <?php endforeach; ?>

        </tr>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

</table>

<?php endif;
```

Some [Demo](http://codepad.org/eH0xQayz) and see as well [Some PHP Iterator Fun](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2012/02/28/some-php-iterator-fun/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=1;
foreach($arr as $val) { 
    if($i == 1) echo '<table><tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $val . '</td>';
    if($i % 3 == 0 && $i != count($arr)) echo '</tr><tr>';
    if($i++ == count($arr)) echo '</tr></table>';
}
```

There's probably a much 'prettier' way to do this but the above works, making use of the [`modulus`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator.