# How to create a php loop to print in specific pattern?

Tags: php, loops

I want to create a PHP Loop so that it should read an array of names and print it in a specific pattern so that on every 4 records, it should close and reopen the new UL element. So in general it should be like below :

```
$names = array('Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3', 'Name 4', 'Name 5', 'Name 6', 'Name 7', 'Name 8', 'Name 9');
```

This is the array I have and I want to create a loop so it should print like this

```
<ul>
    <li>Name 1</li>
    <li>Name 2</li>
    <li>Name 3</li>
    <li>Name 4</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>Name 5</li>
    <li>Name 6</li>
    <li>Name 7</li>
    <li>Name 8</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>Name 9</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is the same concept:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464154/php-table-display-3-cells-in-each-row/9464584#9464584

Comment: No it is slightly different as you noticed here the opening UL and closing UL also need to be inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($names as $key => $value) {
    if ($count%4 == 0) {
        print '<ul>';
    }

    print "<li>$value</li>";

    if ($count%4 == 3) {
        print '</ul>';
    }
    $count++;
}
if (count($names)%4 != 0) {
    print '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: This solution will also give you the closing </ul> if the number of elements in $name is not a multiple of 4. You can optimize this by taking $key instead of $count since they technically serve the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a variable to your loop to be used as a counter.  There's a piece of code that increases it's number on each iteration.  Then you can add an if statement that detects certain numbers (divisible by four in this case) and triggers those list tags to be outputted at the correct interval.  Here is an example of a counter:

```
$i = 0; // Counting variable

foreach ($names as $name) {

  $i++; // Add one to counting variable  

}
```

Always remember to set your counting variable to zero at the beginning, otherwise it may not want to increment (because you can't add one to nothing).  Also, if you use the same variable name in multiple counters on a page, you need to reset them anyway, otherwise the number will be reused in the wrong context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use modulus

```
foreach($names as $key => $name) {
 if ($key % 4 == 0) echo "<ul>"; 
 echo "<li>" . $name . "</li>";
 if ($key % 4 == 0) echo "</ul>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulus operator:

```
$names = array('Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3', 'Name 4', 'Name 5', 'Name 6', 'Name 7', 'Name 8', 'Name 9');
$counter = 0;
foreach($names as $name){
    $counter++;
    if($counter % 4 == 1){
        echo '<ul>';
    }
    echo '<li>'.$name.'</li>';
    if($counter % 4 == 0){
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```