# Implementing grids when outputting SQL data using php

Tags: php, html

Using bootstrap, how would I output details from many rows of data, using php, so that it is structured into rows of 4 columns? When I copied the html into the php, every coloumn was on a single row.

```
 <?php

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){  

  $name = $row['Product_Name'];
  
  $description = $row['Product_Description'];

    ?>
```

rows of 4 columns;

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col">$name + $description here..</div>
  <div class="col">$name + $description here..</div>
  <div class="col">$name + $description here..</div>
  <div class="col">$name + $description here..</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Keep a counter in the loop, then close the div and add a new one if `$counter %4 === 0`. Note that a `<div>` is a block element so it will always be on a row by itself without adding CSS rules.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099568/array-into-a-table-with-5-cells-in-each-row